# firebase sendEmailVerification does not give error on non exisent email address

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an authentication system for my React app with Firebase Auth. When the user signs up, firebase auth registers the user (createUserWithEmailAndPassword) and returns a promise with auth.uid and auth.emailVerified set to "false". This is fine.

I then use sendEmailVerification() method so the email address can be verified. I've tested the code and it works ok for a "valid" and "existing" email address. "catch" does give error for duplicate email address as expected. The problem is, it does not send the NON-EXISTING email (which I suppose is the correct bahaviour) but its should then give an error (so I can display to the user) which it does not.

Can someone explain why I'm not getting error for NON EXISTENT email address?

```
export const unpSignUp = (newUser) => {
    console.log("newUser", newUser);
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        newUser.unp_a05_email,
        newUser.unp_a10_password
        )
        .then((response) => {
        return firestore
            .collection("unps")
            .doc(response.user.uid)
            .set({
                unp_a02_surname: newUser.unp_a02_surname,
                unp_a03_name: newUser.unp_a03_name,
                unp_a06_verify_email_sent_datetime: null,
                unp_a07_email_verified_on_datetime: null,
                unp_a18_acc_created_on_datetime: moment().format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss"),
            });
        })
            .then((response) => {
            console.log("SIGNUP SUCCESS ", response);
            // user has been signed up, next step is to send verification email
            dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_SUCCESS })
        })
        .then(() => {
            // user has been signed up, next step is to send verification email
            console.log('send email adr verification')
            return firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
        })
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log("Verification email sent", response);
            const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
            console.log('current user', user)
            const unp = firestore.collection("unps").doc(user.uid);
            return unp.update({
            unp_a06_verify_email_sent_datetime: moment().format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss"),
            })
        })
        .then( () => {
            console.log(`unp_a06_verify_email_sent_datetime update to ${moment().format("YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss")} `)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("SIGNUP ERROR", error);
            console.log("SIGNUP ERROR CODE", error.code);
            console.log("SIGNUP ERROR MESAGE", error.message);
            dispatch({ type: SIGNUP_ERROR, error });
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [firebase reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendemailverification),

the return type of `sendEmailVerification` is `Promise<void>` - and it does not tell about any error codes that are sent in case of wrong email or failed/bounce mails. The error code it mentions is with respect to `actionCodeSettings`

> If the actionCodeSettings is not specified, no URL is appended to the action URL. The state URL provided must belong to a domain that is whitelisted by the developer in the console. Otherwise an error will be thrown.

Thus it can not be checked if it is a valid email id. (This is expected behaviour as receiving mail servers may be down at times and hence there is a concept of retrying bounce mails)